# Exception while parsing a String into a Date with a defined format

Tags: android

I have the next exception while trying to parse :
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/10/2011 01:24:27.000 PM UTC"

The format defined is

```
private String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa Z";
```

According http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html 
this should work:

```
private String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa Z";
date0 = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse("11/10/2011 01:24:27.000 PM UTC");
```

but it doesn't. The exception is thrown.
Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Works for me on my desktop, Java 1.6u29.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I reproduce this issue on Android.

Answer (score 0):

"Z" means RFC822 timezome, i.e. -0800. Try using small caps "z".

Also, try using "a" instead of "aa".

Answer (score 0):

Is your application multi-threaded, SimepleDateFormat is not thread-safe, always wrap it within  synchronized. check out [here](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html) for details.